# display angular variable values in table according to their position

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a angular variable which has values are [ 170,1,130,3,134,4.... and so on].I want to display it in form such that the values appear in table in two columns for eg. all even position values in one column and all odd position values in other column.

```
col1    col2
170     1
130     3
134     4
```

I have written the following code but it displays all code in a single column. Plz. suggest a solution.Thanks in advance

```
<table class="table">
     <tr ng-repeat="item in output track by $index" ng-switch="$even" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
          <td ng-switch-when="true">{{item}}</td>
          <td ng-switch-default>{{item}}</td> 
     </tr>
```

This is dispplaying the all in one column like:

```
Col1
 170
 1
 130
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the `ngSwitchWhen` on `td`. Instead, use a `div` inside `td` like this:

```
 <td>
     <div ng-switch-when="true">{{item}}</div>
 </td>
 <td>
     <div ng-switch-default>{{item}}</div>
 </td>
```

This will guarantee two columns. One more thing you can do is set the `width` of both `td` for equally sized columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Modulus %" to get the even and odd number and print accordingly. Write your expression in "ng-switch" and check values like below example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

            <span  ng-repeat="obj in items">
                    <div ng-switch on="{{obj%2}}"> 
                        <div ng-switch-when="1">Odd: {{obj}}</div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="0">Even: {{obj}}</div>
                     </div>
      <div></div>

   </div>
            </span>

        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.items = [12,11,34,33,54];                
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1391/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by re-parsing the array in odd an even values:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('dummy', function($scope, $location) {
  var output = [170, 1, 130, 3, 134, 4], odd = [], even = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 2) % 2 == 0) {
      odd.push(output[i]);
    } else {
      even.push(output[i]);
    }
  }
  $scope.output = {odd: odd, even: even};
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="odd in output.odd track by $index">
      <td>{{odd}}</td>
      <td>{{output.even[$index]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/tfqmLvrr/)